# How do I modify file 'jonesforth.S' so that it can return to C caller function without causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, forth

How do I modify file `jonesforth.S` so that it can return to the C caller function without causing a segmentation fault?

https://www.facebook.com/groups/483887212122959/permalink/509343602910653/

https://github.com/udexon/5CSM/blob/master/Progress_20181202.md

(1) The major discovery made since the last report is that, calling syscall __NR_BRK_ will cause segmentation fault AFTER returning from _start1 (jonesforth) to the C caller function (`main()`).

As such, these changes are made in `jonesforth9e.S`:

i. Disable call set_up_data_segment (line 583).

ii. Replace (i) with C malloc (char *) FDSEG (Forth Data Segment) to define var_HERE (line 575).

iii. Doing so solved one problem, but it leaves another unsolved:

a. cat jonesforth.f d.f | jonesforth9e now works. jonesforth.f can be loaded with FDSEG replacing set_up_data_segment.

b. cat jonesforth.f c.f | jonesforth9e still does not work, giving a segmentation fault.

To compile the above: gcc -m32 -o sj9e sj.c jonesforth9e.S -g array.s

Forth script files: c.f d.f

c.f contains a new Forth word, RET, that I created -- to return to the C caller function. Otherwise, jonesforth will exit via syscall __NR_exit. After returning to C caller function (main()) from jonesforth (verified with gdb), seg fault occured when `printf` is called (line 62 in file sj.c).

Comment: If I remember Jonesforth correctly, it makes good use of the way `brk` works: it enlarges the data segment, so all data allocated with `brk` syscalls is right next to each other.  If you replace `brk` with `malloc`, this won't be the case and defining words won't quite work.

Comment: Note that on Stack Overflow, it is highly frowned upon to only link to a third-party site for the source code.  It is your job to boil down your problem into as little code as needed to reproduce it and paste that code into the question.  If you don't do that, other users are going to come and close your question.

Comment: Exactly like @fuz said, all I see is some off-site links and no code.  Classic case of lacking a [mcve].  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/  If there's something interesting to this question, I'd be happy to remove my downvote  and closevote if the question is changed to include code.  But over 500 lines sounds like a bit much for a MCVE.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you saying I have to reproduce everything I wrote in the github link in Stackoverflow?

Are you saying you did not read the github link because it would cost you an extra click?

Comment: I'm saying that Stack Overflow questions have to make sense as self-contained questions.  That's a basic requirement here on SO to make questions resistant to link-rot so they continue to have future value, among other reasons.  Links to a full codebase are fine *in addition* to a MCVE.  See [ask] and the links I posted in the earlier comment.  This questions sounds like it might be potentially more interesting than the usual crap, but I don't know Forth myself so I wasn't interested enough to follow the links.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your interests. I appreciate that. Just to update you that I just "solved" the problem "tentatively". I will update the question / documentation as per SO requirements. Thank you very much for running such a great website which I have been lurking until now. ;-)

https://github.com/udexon/5CSM/blob/master/Progress_20181203.md

Comment: The problem is solved by calling _start1() (jonesforth entry point) in a subfunction, not from main(), so that main's stack is not corrupted.

Although this solution is less than perfect, hopefully it will attract more C programmers to Forth -- and they will solve the remaining problems in the future.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer as an actual *answer* to your own question, not just a comment.  Possibly with slightly more details, but that last comment might be enough for a future reader to solve the same problem.  Now that you have an answer for your own question, bending the off-topic-question / MCVE rules is less of an issue.  (Still not ideal...)

Comment: Just a quick note to say that, it is perhaps preferable, safer and more reliable to call jonesforth _start1() within a "wrapper" function as suggested above, as gcc will do the necessary housekeeping for the registers, stack etc. I will do my best to update the question and solution as I believe this is a unique and very interesting test case spawning Forth, C and assembly programming.

Comment: Someone informed me of [eForth](http://home.iae.nl/users/mhx/eforth.html) -- a very old implementation of Forth with no recent documentation.

It seems to have a facility to call Forth from C. I have yet to check it out.

Just leave this comment just in case anyone wants to test it before I do.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be better to keep to the Q&A format (keeping questions and solutions separate in, well, questions and answers): Move the relevant information from the question and comments to an answer. Self-answering is 100% acceptable (and encouraged). As not all users understand this, it is best to leave a comment on your answer. E.g. pointing to *[Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463)*.

Answer (score 2):

A tentative solution is given here:

https://github.com/udexon/5CSM/blob/master/Progress_20181203.md

TLDR: put jonesforth in a C wrapper function. Let GCC handles the stack.

Need more time to figure out bug free solution.